# When creating a custom checkbox, a grey icon is displayed instead of the selected custom drawable

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create custom round checkbox. But instead of the selected images, a grey icon is displayed.

[image]

My checkbox declaration:

```
<CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/beAnonymousTextView"
        style="@style/TextViewStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="I want to be anonymous"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/emailButton"
        android:button="@drawable/custom_checkbox"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"/>
```

My custom drawable selector:

```
custom_checkbox.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/custom_checkbox_selected" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/custom_checkbox_selected" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/custom_checkbox_unselected" android:state_checked="false" />
</selector>
```

My custom drawable:

```
custom_checkbox_selected.xml

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="@color/orange" /> 
    <stroke android:color="@color/white" android:width="3dp" />
    <size
        android:width="30dp"
        android:height="30dp" />
</shape>
```

```
custom_checkbox_unselected.xml

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval">
    <stroke android:color="@color/white" android:width="3dp" />
    <size
        android:width="30dp"
        android:height="30dp" />
</shape>
```

Comment: Can you show the "TextViewStyle"?

Comment: <style name="TextViewStyle">
        <item name="android:textSize">28sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="fontFamily">@font/montserrat_bold</item>
    </style>

Answer (score 0):

**A simple way:**

Add android:buttonTint="@null" to your CheckBox

**Another way:**

Your custom drawable selector `custom_checkbox.xml`:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="@color/orange" /> 
    <stroke android:color="@color/white" android:width="3dp" />
    <size
        android:width="30dp"
        android:height="30dp" />
</shape>
```

Your color selector: (place it on `res/color` folder) `custom_checkbox_color_selector.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/grey" android:state_enabled="false" />
    <item android:color="@color/orange" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/orange" android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/orange" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/white" />
</selector>
```

Your `CheckBox`:

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/beAnonymousTextView"
    style="@style/TextViewStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:text="I want to be anonymous"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/emailButton"
    android:buttonTint="@color/custom_checkbox_color_selector"
    android:button="@drawable/custom_checkbox"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"/>
```